# TFS 2015 build can't build .NET Core

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, .net-core, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We are really starting to get frustruated now with our development of .NET Core applications.

We have a solution/repository where we have gathered all our .NET core projects, it works fine locally to build within Visual Studio 2015, but as soon as we try to setup CI builds and other builds they all fails.

The error that we always get back to is the infamous `"GETSDKTOOLINGINFO(0,0): Error : The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 which is not installed or cannot be found."`

We are running `dotnet restore` before with no luck. We have more or less tried everything.

**And here comes the annoying part, and the actually issue:**

If we copy the build command and run it locally on the build agent server in a normal command prompt it works just fine, with no errors

For instance this command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\msbuild.exe" "D:\_work\11\s\core.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=D:\_work\11\s\core.sln.log" /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"`

*Don't work through the TFS build.*

***The command does work locally on the build agent machine.***

*EDIT 1: Below screen show that we do not use any special build step. We have changed to "msbuild build step" with the same bad result.*

[image]

*EDIT 2: Log*

```
2017-02-23T08:24:34.3679600Z Starting task: Build solution
2017-02-23T08:24:34.4304594Z Executing the powershell script: D:\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.16\VSBuild.ps1
2017-02-23T08:24:34.6335861Z D:\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" -NonInteractive
2017-02-23T08:24:35.0085872Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
2017-02-23T08:24:35.1335875Z Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.0.
2017-02-23T08:24:35.4054303Z Adding package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.0' to folder 'D:\_work\5\s\packages'
2017-02-23T08:24:35.7960574Z Added package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.0' to folder 'D:\_work\5\s\packages'
2017-02-23T08:24:35.8273065Z C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false /t:"Clean" /fl /flp:"logfile=D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln-clean.log" /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="x64" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
2017-02-23T08:24:35.9210571Z Build started 2017-02-23 09:24:35.
2017-02-23T08:24:35.9523075Z      1>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:35.9523075Z      1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2017-02-23T08:24:35.9523075Z          Building solution configuration "release|x64".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.0148080Z      1>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (1) is building "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Log\Log.xproj" (2) on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.0148080Z      2>CoreClean:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.0148080Z          Creating directory ".\obj\Release\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.0148080Z      2>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Log\Log.xproj" (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.2648091Z      1>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (1) is building "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\FronEnd.sfproj" (5) on node 4 (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.2648091Z      5>CoreClean:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.2648091Z          Creating directory "obj\x64\Release\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3116863Z      5>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\FronEnd.sfproj" (5) is building "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\Portal.xproj" (6) on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3116863Z      6>CoreClean:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3116863Z          Creating directory ".\obj\Release\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3585616Z        PreComputeCompileTypeScript:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3585616Z          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3585616Z      6>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\Portal.xproj" (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3585616Z      5>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\FronEnd.sfproj" (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z      1>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (1) is building "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Core\Core.xproj.metaproj" (8) on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z      8>Project "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Core\Core.xproj.metaproj" (8) is building "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Core\Core.xproj" (9) on node 2 (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z      9>CoreClean:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z          Creating directory ".\obj\Release\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z      9>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Core\Core.xproj" (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z      8>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Core\Core.xproj.metaproj" (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z      1>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (Clean target(s)).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z Build succeeded.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z     0 Warning(s)
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z     0 Error(s)
2017-02-23T08:24:36.3898104Z Time Elapsed 00:00:00.46
2017-02-23T08:24:36.4054367Z C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln.log" /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="x64" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
2017-02-23T08:24:36.4835619Z Build started 2017-02-23 09:24:36.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.4991873Z      1>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.4991873Z      1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.4991873Z          Building solution configuration "release|x64".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.5460612Z      1>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (1) is building "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\FronEnd.sfproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.5460612Z      2>PrepareForBuild:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.5460612Z          Creating directory "bin\Release\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8273147Z      2>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\FronEnd.sfproj" (2) is building "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\Portal.xproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8273147Z      3>PrepareForBuild:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8273147Z          Creating directory ".\bin\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8273147Z        PreComputeCompileTypeScript:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8273147Z          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8273147Z        CompileTypeScript:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8273147Z          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8429390Z ##[error]GETSDKTOOLINGINFO(0,0): Error : The .NET Core SDK is not installed or cannot be found. These components are required to build and run this project.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8429390Z      3>GETSDKTOOLINGINFO : error : The .NET Core SDK is not installed or cannot be found. These components are required to build and run this project. [D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\Portal.xproj]
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8429390Z      1>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (1) is building "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Configuration.Core\Configuration.Core.xproj" (5) on node 2 (default targets).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8429390Z      5>PrepareForBuild:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8429390Z          Creating directory ".\bin\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8429390Z      3>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\Portal.xproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8429390Z      2>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\FronEnd.sfproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8585648Z      5>Project "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Configuration.Core\Configuration.Core.xproj" (5) is building "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Core\Core.xproj" (7) on node 2 (default targets).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8585648Z      7>PrepareForBuild:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8585648Z          Creating directory ".\bin\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8898141Z      1>Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (1) is building "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Log\Log.xproj" (6) on node 4 (default targets).
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8898141Z      6>PrepareForBuild:
2017-02-23T08:24:36.8898141Z          Creating directory ".\bin\".
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9054497Z ##[error]GETSDKTOOLINGINFO(0,0): Error : The .NET Core SDK is not installed or cannot be found. These components are required to build and run this project.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9054497Z      6>GETSDKTOOLINGINFO : error : The .NET Core SDK is not installed or cannot be found. These components are required to build and run this project. [D:\_work\5\s\Common\Log\Log.xproj]
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9054497Z      6>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Log\Log.xproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9054497Z      7>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Core\Core.xproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z      1>Done Building Project "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z Build FAILED.
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z        "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z        "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\FronEnd.sfproj" (default target) (2) ->
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z        "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\Portal.xproj" (default target) (3) ->
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z        (GetSDKToolingInfoTarget target) -> 
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z          GETSDKTOOLINGINFO : error : The .NET Core SDK is not installed or cannot be found. These components are required to build and run this project. [D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric\Clients\Portal.xproj]
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z        "D:\_work\5\s\ServiceFabric.Frontend.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z        "D:\_work\5\s\Common\Log\Log.xproj" (default target) (6) ->
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z          GETSDKTOOLINGINFO : error : The .NET Core SDK is not installed or cannot be found. These components are required to build and run this project. [D:\_work\5\s\Common\Log\Log.xproj]
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z     0 Warning(s)
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z     2 Error(s)
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9210662Z Time Elapsed 00:00:00.43
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9366903Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received from msbuild.exe: 1
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9679398Z Finishing task: VSBuild
2017-02-23T08:24:36.9835654Z ##[error]Task VSBuild failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
```

Anyone that have had this problem and got pass it?

We feel basically stuck atm!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to install .net core SDK in TFS build agent.

Comment: @Venky - We are not running TeamCity, we are running TFS. And please read the post before answering...

Comment: You just need to wait for a few more days. On March 7 when Microsoft officially releases .NET Core SDK 1.0, your vendor should be able to provide you some support on building .NET Core projects based on that. The preview 2.1 you use is really out of date.

Comment: Could you share your build definition and detailed log? Have you installed .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 on your build agent machine?

Comment: Added screen and log. And yes, I have installed the SDK, and verified it with dotnet --version. And as I mentioned, the build command works in a command prompt on the build agant machine (locally)

Comment: @J.Abrahamsson, How about run with "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" manually on your build agent machine?

Comment: @Cece, well, that doesn't give us any automatically CI builds, which is kinda the whole point with the tfs builds...

Comment: What's the result if you build the project by using dotnet build? On the other hand, try to setup a build agent running as interactive mode, then queue build with this build agent and check the result.

Comment: @starain; Thanks for the tips of dotnet build. Not sure what you mean by the other things but I actually think I have found a solution. Working with it as I write and if all things fall into pieces I will post an update, or even a solution answer... :)

Comment: @J.Abrahamsson Feel free to post the update or an answer.

Comment: Regarding interactive mode. The build agent can be running as service and interactive mode (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v1-windows)

Comment: Your problem is here MSBuild 14.  
If you / we could get it to use MSBuild 15 then we would be able to get this to build .NET Core

MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0'

Comment: Ah, sorry. Missed to update this one. This is not an issue anymore. It was due to the preview version. When it was finally release it was buildable/deployable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue after the release, was connect to the preview state in some way, not sure exactly what the wrong was. But it's not wrong anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Team Foundation Server (TFS) build definition, add command line build steps to restore, build, test, pack, and publish routines. (They will be separate build steps, and test, pack, and publish will be needed for each VS Project).

This presumes of course you got the dotnet cli tools installed on the TFS Build Agents.

Basically, just mimic what you would do with at command line on your dev machine on the build server.